# Change the first character in each word of a string to uppercase

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I found the function below :

***CFStringCapitalize***

"Changes the first character in each word of a string to uppercase (if it is a lowercase alphabetical character)."

```
void CFStringCapitalize (
   CFMutableStringRef theString,
   CFLocaleRef locale
);
```

Does anyone know how to use it with my NSMutableString ?

Thank you,

Gauthier.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The capitalizedString method exists in NSString class, see [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/capitalizedString)

```
NSString *foo = @"this is all lower";
NSString *fooUpper = [foo capitalizedString];
```

Note that this isn't iPhone specific, same code on the Mac.

Comment: can hardly agree, as `capitalizedString` will set the rest of the string to lower case. e.g. `completionHandler` will become `Completionhandler`, note the 'H', tested on iOS15

Answer (score 6):

```
(NSString *)capitalizedString
```

So:

```
NSString *myString,*myCapitalizedString;

myString = @"capitalize";
myCapitalizedString = [myString capitalizedString]; //produces a capitalized copy of 'myString'
```