# UPPERCASE Characters Convert to Case Sensitive in Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, string

In my Project there are some names which coming from Database
But Problem is that all characters are coming in uppercase(as if i store in uppercase)
but i want that characters should come like this....

SANJAY YADAV  "Sanjay Yadav"

It Should be Case Sensitive

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this : [Change the first character in each word of a string to uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347786/change-the-first-character-in-each-word-of-a-string-to-uppercase)

if it doesn't work then convert all letters to lowercase and then do the above url

Answer (score 7):

You can make all your text in upper case / lower case and then do your code

```
NSString *username1 = [userName uppercaseString];
NSString *username1 = [userName lowercaseString];
```

Note: userName is NSString

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I want like this.. If i have one name "ABCDEF" and wants to convert in "Abcdef"  .. How it possible..?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use NSString function "capitalizedString" for this.
NSString *fooUpper = [foo capitalizedString];