# NSFetchedResultsController - out of order section error

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I’m setting an NSFetchedResultsController with the sort descriptor

```
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@”name” ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

And the section

```
aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@”name” cacheName:nil];
```

Then I also set the table view section’s delegate like this:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.fetchedController sectionIndexTitles];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [self.fetchedController sectionForSectionIndexTitle:title atIndex:index];
}
```

Sometimes, when I insert objects, I’m getting the error "The fetched object at index X has an out of order section name 'something. Objects must be sorted by section name'";

I’m inserting thousands of rows. When the error happens, it’s always with the same case: I have 10 objects called the same thing, but some are upper case and others are lower case. Example: nameexample, nameExample, nameEXAMPLE, nameexample, nameExample, etc.

Any idea why do I get the error and how can I fix this?
The reason why I have it case insensitive is because my sections are based on the first letter and if I don’t have it case insensitive I’ll get section ‘a’ and section ‘A’.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the order of the section is different from the order of the sort because although I'm using the same attribute, one is case insensitive and the other isn't.

Solution: I've added another attribute in the Core Data which contains the name in lower case and I use this attribute in the section and sort. This way I don't have to call @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me when I say that duplicating data makes me cringe for two reasons:

- Although devices hosting iOS appear very capable, they are much more
  resource-constrained than say an iMac.  Meaning: space and time are
  much more significant factors when targeting tablets and smart
  phones.
- Regardless, why put yourself through the trouble of
  maintaining two roughly identical data sets?

For those out there that are space-conscious or reflexive-minded: I would think a more appropriate solution forces the stored data lower case before committing to the data model; and systematically adjusts the letters prior to display.  In theory, this makes the search simpler (faster), and definitely requires less memory.

Or, perhaps it's more appropriate to capitalize the first letter of any number of strings prior to committing to the data model.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347786/change-the-first-character-in-each-word-of-a-string-to-uppercase) clarifies that you can use

```
managedObject.string = [stringToBeCommitted capitalizedString];
NSError *error = nil;
if(![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    ...
}
```

for this purpose.