# How can i make first letter of all words in a string into uppercase iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the first character in each word of a string to uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347786/change-the-first-character-in-each-word-of-a-string-to-uppercase)

I have a string

**"this is a string"**

How can i convert first word of a string into uppercase

**"This Is A String"**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume you're using `NSString`

```
NSString *str=@"this is a string";
NSString *titleStr = [str capitalizedString];

NSLog(@"%@", titleStr); // Outputs: "This Is A String"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use capitalizedString , Just take a lock on  [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

```
NSString *newString = [yourStr capitalizedString];
```