# How to capitalized first letter of Label

Tags: iphone, uilabel

Here's my code :-

I need to Change only the first letter of the Word to capitalized.

```
UILabel *lbl4=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 90, 200, 30)];
lbl4.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)", [arrtype  objectAtIndex:0]];
lbl4.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18];
lbl4.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
lbl4.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14629780/2106973

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capitalization is for string not label

use

```
[NSString capitalizedString]
```

to capitalise a string and set it as text to the label

```
lbl4.text= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)", [arrtype  objectAtIndex:0]]capitalizedString];
```

Comment: Note that this will make all the other letters, following the first, lowercase, which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
UILabel *lbl4=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 90, 200, 30)];

NSString *abc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)", [arrtype  objectAtIndex:0]];

abc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[abc substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString],[abc substringFromIndex:1]];

lbl4.text = abc;

lbl4.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18];

lbl4.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

lbl4.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *abc = @"demo";
abc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[abc substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString],[abc substringFromIndex:1] ];       
NSLog(@"abc = %@",abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *) capitalizedFirstLetter:(NSString *)stringToConvert 
{
NSString *retVal = stringToConvert;
if (stringToConvert.length <= 1) 
{
    retVal = stringToConvert.capitalizedString;
}else 
{
   retVal= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[retVal substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString],[retVal substringFromIndex:1] ];
}
return retVal;
}
```

call this method:
[self capitalizedFirstLetter:labelName or textFieldName];