# Replacing one character in a string in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, string, nsstring

Hoping somebody can help me out - I would like to replace a certain character in a string and am wondering what is the best way to do this?

I know the location of the character, so for example, if I want to change the 3rd character in a string from A to B - how would I code that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778227/string-manipulation-in-objective-c

Comment: Here is simple method that can do your work.Have a try.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953044/replace-a-character-at-a-certain-index-in-nsstring/24860376#24860376

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If it is always the same character you can use:

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:
```

If it is the same string in the same location you can use:

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:
```

If is just a specific location you can use:

```
stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:
```

Documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring

So for example:

```
NSString *someText = @"Goat";
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,1);
NSString *newText = [someText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"B"];
```

newText would equal "Boat"

Comment: Thanks for adding the code example. For others who may be wondering, the '0' in NSMakeRange is the character's position, and the '1' is the length starting at character 0 that you wish to replace - so to replace the first character you do (0,1) to replace the third character you do (2,1) and so forth.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 32):

```
NSString *str = @"123*abc";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"*" withString:@""];
//str now 123abc
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is the code:

```
[aString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(3,1) withString:@"B"];
```

Comment: +0.5 because code is king, but this will replace the wrong letter ^^

Comment: @fluchtpunkt: Thanks. But this is just an example.

Comment: It does what you wanted now. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use the `replaceCharactersInRange: withString:` message on a `NSMutableString` object.