# Replace character in string

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, nsstring

I have a `NSMutableString` `@"hello"`. I'd like to replace the character at the second position, 'e' with 'a' so that it reads `@"hallo"`. How do I do that?

I have tried this to implement a Shift Cipher, but it throws an `IndexOutBoundsException`

```
- (NSString*)encode:(NSString*)original withShift:(int)shift {

    NSMutableString* encoded = [NSMutableString stringWithString:original];
    for (int i=0; i < [encoded length]; i++) {
        char oriChar = [encoded characterAtIndex:i];
        if (oriChar == ' ') {
            continue;
        }
        char encChar = ((oriChar - LETTER_POS) + shift) % ALPHABET_LENGTH + LETTER_POS;

        NSRange range = {i, i};
        [encoded replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:&encChar]];

    }
    return encoded;

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing one character in a string - iPhone/iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223701/replacing-one-character-in-a-string-iphone-ipad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSRange r = {1,1}; //String indexing is 0-based
[s replaceCharactersInRange: r withString:@"a"]
```

Also, do learn to use the online reference.

Comment: Or use [AppKiDo](http://homepage.mac.com/aglee/downloads/appkido.html) for reference, it's free and uses the Apple documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` of [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Comment: I see. Can I replace the character only at a specified index?

Comment: use 'stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:' instead.