# Replace a character at a certain index in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, replace, nsstring

I'm looking for a way to replace a character at a certain index of a NSString.

For example: `myString = @"******";`

I want to replace the 3rd " * " with an "A", so that the string looks like this: `myString = @"**A***";`

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try with this link. It has the same problem that you are having. http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/76235-nsstring-how-replace-character-certain-index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940104/replace-character-in-string

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try with this:

```
NSString *str = @"*******";
str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(3, 1) withString:@"A"];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Answer (score 18):

There are really two options;

Since NSString is read-only, you need to call `mutableCopy` on the NSString to get an NSMutableString that can actually be changed, then call `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` on the NSMutableString to replace the characters in it. This is more efficient if you want to change the string more than once.

There is also a `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:` method on NSString that returns a new NSString with the characters replaced. This may be more efficient for a single change, but requires you to create a new NSString for each replacement.

Answer (score 4):

Try this sample method

```
-(NSString *)string:(NSString*)string ByReplacingACharacterAtIndex:(int)i byCharacter:(NSString*)StringContainingAChar{

    return [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1) withString:StringContainingAChar];

}
```

if your string is "testing" and you want first character "t" should be replaced with "*" than call method

```
[self string:yourString ByReplacingACharacterAtIndex:0 byCharacter:@"*"]
```

Run and Go

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a little C, use something like this:

```
char *str = (char *)[myString UTF8String];
str[2] = 'A';
myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:str];
```

Of course you should be absolutely sure that myString has at least 3 characters before doing this. Other than that, it's a very fast and efficient way to do something like this.

Comment: Works in iOS, but doesn't on MacOS. I believe MacOS returns newly allocated string.

Answer (score 0):

My contribution with a swift extension from the response :

```
extension NSString{

    func replacingACharacterAtIndex(pIndex : Int, pChar : Character) -> NSString{

        return self.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(NSRange(location: pIndex, length: 1), withString: String(pChar))
    }
}
```