# How to read array of array in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to read this but unable to get proper value.

```
NSString *arr = [self.myArray valueForKey:@"description"];
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```

I'm getting this output :

```
(
        (
        050,
        051
    )
)
```

And also it should remove first `0 i.e 050->50`

But I want it as single array, like this [50, 51]

I'm newbie, please help me out.

Comment: please let us know what is the structure of `self.myArray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
NSArray *arr = [[self.myArray valueForKey:@"description"]objectAtIndex: 0];
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```

Also to remove the first 0 from string, You can try `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange` providing the place of 0.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953044/replace-a-character-at-a-certain-index-in-nsstring) can help you

Comment: @Aadi, Glad. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
NSArray * NewArray = [[self.myArray valueForKey:@"description"]objectAtIndex: 0];
NSLog(@"New Array is %@", NewArray);
```

Comment: arr is NSString, so it is giving me error for `objectAtIndex`

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code

```
 [myArray setObject:arr2 forKey:@"description"];
    for (NSString *st in [[myArray valueForKey:@"description"] objectAtIndex:0]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",st);
        NSString *firstChar = [st substringToIndex:1];
        if ([firstChar  isEqual: @"0"]) {
            NSString *newStr = [st substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [st length]-1)];
            NSLog(@"%@",newStr);
        }
    }
```

**OutPut:**
050
50
051
51

Comment: is there any need to convert Array to string?

Comment: to remove 0 from the start.