# Replace a character in a String iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsstring

I want to replace a single character at a particular position in a string.

*Example*

*String: 123-456-7890*

*Desired Output: 123-406-7890 (Replacing 5 at fifth position with 0)*

Comment: Its duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5223701/1030951

Comment: everybody has given rite answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:`, forming the `NSRange` variable to indicate the 5th position.

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"123-456-7890";
NSString *newString = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(5, 1) withString:@"0"];
NSLog(@"%@", newString);
```

`Output: 123-406-7890`

Read all about [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/).

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/

visit here and read all about string

Answer (score 0):

for replacing string there are lots of way:

```
NSString *str = [yourString stringByReplacingOccuranceOfString:@"5" withString:@"0"];
```

second way first get range of string like:

```
NSRange range = [yourSting rangeOfString:@"5"];
NSString *first = [yourString substringToIndex:range.location];
NSString *second = [yourString substringFromIndex:range.location+range.length];
NSString *yourNewStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0%@",first,second];
```

Tere are lots of other using string operation but First one is best in that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually replace the 5th character rather than just any 5 you need to make a range first.

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(5, 1);
NSString *newString = [initialString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"0"];
```

Edit: Corrected make range length

Comment: Your range (`NSMakeRange(5, 5)`) is currently incorrect to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :-

```
NSString *replacechar = @"0";
NSString *newString= [String stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(5,1) withString:replacechar];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the range (i.e. index) of first occurrence of the substring. 
Then replace at that range with your desired replace value.

```
NSString *originalString = @"123 456 789";
NSRange r = [originalString rangeOfString:@"5"];
NSString *newString = [originalString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@"0"];
```