# remove "\n" and "\" from nsstring in iPhone...?

Tags: iphone, json, nsdictionary, html-escape-characters

I have a iPhone application which return me a string from webservice with escape characters like "\n" and "\". Now I want to add this string in nsdictionary. for that I do below

```
    NSMutableArray *keyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSMutableArray *valueArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

[valueArray addObject:strVerifiedReceipt];
[keyArray addObject:@"PAYMENT_RECEIPT"];

NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:valueArray forKeys:keyArray];
NSString* jsonString = [jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];
```

here jsonString return me strVerifiedReceipt with escape characters come from webservice like below

> ```
> "PAYMENT_RECEIPT": "{\n\"receipt\":{\"original_purchase_date_pst\":\"2012-10-10 03:29:12 America/Los_Angeles\", \"unique_identifier\":\"977ce60f38d875d12d0f1d7fe583d1d5e61f99e8\", \"original_transaction_id\":\"1000000056917869\", \"bvrs\":\"2.0\", \"transaction_id\":\"1000000056917869\", \"quantity\":\"1\", \"product_id\":\"com.cornerstonehealthtechnologies.meanexus.Nexus010\", \"item_id\":\"544678366\", \"purchase_date_ms\":\"1349864952265\", \"purchase_date\":\"2012-10-10 10:29:12 Etc/GMT\", \"original_purchase_date\":\"2012-10-10 10:29:12 Etc/GMT\", \"purchase_date_pst\":\"2012-10-10 03:29:12 America/Los_Angeles\", \"bid\":\"com.cornerstonehealthtechnologies.meanexus\", \"original_purchase_date_ms\":\"1349864952265\"}, \"status\":0}",
> ```

Comment: [Replace multiple characters in a string in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/714009/1059705) , [Replacing one character in a string - iPhone/iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5223737/1059705)

Comment: have you find an option for this? I have same problem. I need to remove just "\"

Answer (score 1):

Use **stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:**

```
jsonString = [[[jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"
                                                        withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\" withString:@""]
```

Comment: Thanks but already try this type of options, but it only replaces \n and not \ from my string

Answer (score 1):

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` will definitely work, but to remove the backslashes, make sure you put 2, because putting just one will just escape the quotation mark.

```
jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea to remove backslash `\` from your jsonString

```
jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",[jsonString UTF8String]]
```

And it is working for me and it gives me a valid JSON string.

Answer (score -1):

```
jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\" withString:@""];
```

Comment: while this code block might answer the question, you should try to improve your answer by adding relevant explanation with the code see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer