# UITextfield format ****user

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I want to add masked and unmasked characters, both together in `UITextfield`.

e.g I have a `UITextField` called UserName "**TestUser**". Now I want to display username in the `UITextField` like "****User". Is it possible to add both text together? I want to do this thing while entering character in `UITextfield`.

Comment: Well, how about extending the UITextfield class, create a new private String with the unencrypted text, make a new get for the unencrypted string and override the setter to set the unencrypetd to your private String and the encrypted to the normal String

Comment: Is there is any specific set or length of letters you want to mask?

Comment: @the_UB yes... first four characters to be masked.. rest of the characters to be unmasked..

Comment: [This might be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223701/replacing-one-character-in-a-string-in-objective-c), you have to set range (0-3) and replace it with  '*'.

One more question : Do you want to replace it while user to typing?

Comment: @the_UB , yup.. I want to replace it while user is typing.... in above solution.. we are actually replacing the character with other character.. I don't want to replace my actual string.. I just want to mask it..

Comment: @Dishant 
UITextField.secureTextEntry = YES  if you setting this line it again start to create textFiled secure form first character. so  i think this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth your while to look at the text field delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

It is called

> "whenever the user types a new character in the text field or deletes an existing character"

So you can set the range 0-3 or whatever you like to "*" but you should hold the first characters somewhere else, which I believe to be possible before returning yes, with the textField parameter provided. I don't know if you tried this already or not and I haven't tried this myself, but let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

something I figure out and made below solution but **still it is not exactly that I want**. I want to mask/asterisks first four characters while entering values in `UITextField`. But here I am doing this thing on `textFieldShouldReturn` method.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Store orignal string - we can use later
    _strOriginalString = textField.text;

    //Make temporary Masked String
    NSRange replacementRange = NSMakeRange(0, 4);
    _strMaskString = [NSMutableString new];

    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        [_strMaskString appendString:@"●"];
    }

    //Replace Orignal String's Range with Masked string
    self.txtUsername.text = [_strOriginalString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:replacementRange withString:_strMaskString];

    NSLog(@"Textfield string - %@",self.txtUsername.text);
    NSLog(@"orignal string  - %@",_strOriginalString);
    NSLog(@"masked string - %@",_strMaskString);

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer to your question. You should update your question with this information.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think, that this is possible. Why do you want to show the name like "****User" in the UITextfield? You can use a label and mask the first characters with *