# How to edit the contents while http Post?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, ios4, ios-simulator

hi friends im getting the data ie HTML contents from the following code..

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
    NSString *htmlSTR = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"%@" , htmlSTR);
}
```

if i want to edit some of the contents in HTML page and then want to post it, how can i do that?

eg: if im using gmail account, and when i will get HTML contents of gmail, i want to enter the mail-id and password in html page (Without using the pre-defined UI) and then want to post the contents.. so that when i will click on gmail in my option it should directly log-in without showing log-in page..

can we do this and if yes then how in objective C.?

Comment: Do you want to modify the content returned by the web service? OR You want to post something to web service?

Comment: You can use String Manipulation to achieve your goal. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778227/string-manipulation-in-objective-c

Comment: @Matt : i want to modify the returned content and also want to post it back to service..

Comment: @Raju See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

method gets called multiple times while web service is returning response, So it would be better to change the data into:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

You can do as following:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *htmlSTR = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableString *strToBeChanged = [NSMutableString stringWithString:htmlSTR];
    // Perform changes to strToBeChanged.
}
```

Hope this makes sense to you.